# Editing multiple line code on perticular place like sublime in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Editing multiple line code on particular place like sublime in netbeans
ctl+shft+r you can write in block but if i want write in particular place, Like if i want edit 1st variable in 1st line, 3 variable in 2nd line like that same like a sunlime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans 8.2 supports multi caret editing (multi cursor), check this wiki for details http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#Editor_Multicarets